# MPI bind ranks to specific nodes via Slurm

Tags: mpi, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I use sbatch to allocate an MPI job with (let's say) 8 ranks.
I use 4 nodes: `node0[01-04]`.
I would like to bind rank 0 to the first node (`node001`) and the other ranks to the other nodes (`node0[02-04]`).
How can it be done using sbatch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html environment variables

**SLURM_NODEID**  will give you the ID of the node in the allocation

**SLURM_NNODES** will give you the total amount of nodes allocated.

If you want to specific about ensuring the order of the nodes matches the rank you will also need to parse.

**SLURM_JOB_NODELIST**